# set new offset_top for stick_in_parent

Tags: jquery, sticky

I used the `sticky-kit` framework for the Jquery to `fix the sidebar`. And I did it successfully, and it's like [that](https://codepen.io/sharnirio/pen/jOOryRV)

And this site has put this code in its `js` section . `offset_top: 10`

This height is maintained from both the scroll down and the scroll up mode. And it works right

> I want to change this to 10 pixels if you scroll up. And if you scroll
> down, have a distance of 0 pixels

And so I wrote the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
            if (scroll_to_top) {
                    $("#aside").stick_in_parent({
                        offset_top: 10
                    });
            }
            if (scroll_to_down) {
                    $("#aside").stick_in_parent({
                        offset_top: 0
                    });
            }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        if (scroll_to_top) {
                $("#aside").css({
                    "top": "10px"
                });

        }
        if (scroll_to_down) {
                $("#aside").css({
                    "top": "0px"
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set new `offset_top` you should remove sticky kit and restore element by triggering `'sticky_kit:detach'` event:

```
if (scroll_to_top) {
  $("#aside").trigger('sticky_kit:detach');
  $("#aside").stick_in_parent({
    offset_top: 10
  });
}
if (scroll_to_down) {
  $("#aside").trigger('sticky_kit:detach');
  $("#aside").stick_in_parent({
    offset_top: 0
  });
}
```